# ASP.NET MVC find what page sent the Ajax request

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, profiling, httprequest

I'm implementing profiling for our site, and I'm basically just using timers in `Application_BeginRequest()` and `Application_EndRequest()` to track the request times.

The issue is that in `Application_EndRequest()`, I can get the Ajax request's URL by `Request.RawUrl`, but how can I get which page sent this request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check `Request.UrlReferrer` to get the page from which the request originated but keep in mind that some browser may not send referer in ajax requests and you should account for this case in your code.

Alternatively, you should pass an additional parameter containing the current url in all your ajax calls.

Comment: Awesome! Just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Along with that you can use below code to pass the requesting page url

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     jQuery.ajaxSetup({
          beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
                xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Referrer', location.href);//this will do
                return xhr;
          }
     });
});
```

and on server side , use an actionfilter and put IsAjaxRequest property in your controller class

```
[AjaxDetector]
public abstract class SomeController : Controller
{
   public bool IsAjaxRequest { get; set; }
   public string Referrer { get; set; }
}

public class AjaxDetector : ActionFilterAttribute  
{  
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)  
    {   
        SomeController someController = filterContext.Controller as SomeController;
        if (myController != null)
        {
            if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] != null
                && filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Requested-With"] == "XMLHttpRequest")
            {
                someController.IsAjaxRequest = true;
                someController.Referrer=filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers["X-Referrer"]
            }
            else
            {
                someController.IsAjaxRequest = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```